# Link remains :hover'ed when opened from JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

This might be a little interesting for people who know front-end in depth.

**This doesn't make sense, try it yourself:**

1. Open a link with `href` + `target="_blank"`
2. Close the opened tab and go back to the original
3. The link state is now `:focus`

**That is fine. But what is wrong with this?**

1. Open a link with `window.open()` on click event
2. Close the opened tab and go back to the original
3. ***The link state is now `:hover`, even though it's not really hovered. And you can't do anything about it unless you start moving cursor. `trigger('mouseout')` doesn't help and nothing really does.***

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maxflex/fxg680bo/) – I've added a `console.log()` output for each event and made states different colors, so you can see better.

Comment: I just tried the JSFiddle you created and it is working fine. What browser are you using?

Comment: JSFiddle works fine for me in Firefox (technically Iceweasel).

Comment: Tried in the latest versions of Chrome and Safari. Isn't the link red when you go back to the original tab (and haven't yet moved cursor)?

Comment: No problem for me, on Chrome 43.0.2357.81 (64-bit) for Linux (Xubuntu)

Comment: Nope, link is black. I am using Chrome v43 and I tried it in IE 9

Comment: Wait, link is red indeed, but only if I don't move the mouse at all and use keyboard shortcuts to close the tab.

Comment: Could you tell us how that behavior is ruining your site?

Comment: @JacqueGoupil for me it's red until I move somewhere in the window (when I move cursor in the tabs area – it remains red). But it doesn't matter. How can I make the hover go away as soon as it goes to another tab? (the way it works in regular `href` + `target="_blank"`)

Comment: As I said in my other comment, you could could add a class that invalidates the :hover when you click it, and remove it on mousein event.

Comment: @oscargilfc that's a good trick to solve the problem, but I want to understand the behaviour on this one. Also, there is an even better solution (for me, at least) – open a link with `mousedown` event. This way it works the way it should be and the link isn't hovered when going back to the original tab.

Comment: Well, I think that's browser developers fault.

Answer (score 0):

Browser keeps `:hover`status until the mouse passes over other thing, if the mouse remained in the same position when you open the new window/tab, it will keep the `:hover`. When you return the focus to the page the `:hover` will remove as soon you pass the mouse over something else. That behavior could be buggy in some computers(not necessarily browser fault) and will stay until you click in another place.

Comment: Okay, let it be so. But why is `trigger('mouseout')`  not helping there?  It does in every other case.

Comment: mouseout is a javascript event, which isn't responsible for CSS hover style. After all, :hover works if JavaScript is disabled. As far as the CSS engine goes, the cursor is still over the link.

Comment: You could add a class that invalidates the `:hover` when you click it, and remove it on `mousein` event.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil but why the CSS engine consider the link not hovered when you open it from `href`? The cursor doesn't move in either case.